# Python Powers and Exponents

Tags: python

What would be the best implementation for multiplying a list of numbers raised to a defined number of exponents.

Currently I have a list of 8 numbers that would be needed to be raised to a power. Every list will always contain 8 numbers and the numbers in the list will always have the exponent of which their index value is.

For example:

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Power(1,0) + Power(2,1) + Power(3,2) +.... Power(8,7)
```

However, the issue is what if the list has a none value, how can you carry the exponential increased value without affecting the total sum.

Example:

```
List = [1,None,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Power(1,0) + (none) + Power(3,2) +.... Power(8,7)
```

Any ideas of implementation would help.

Comment: Are the numbers and powers always in order like that? Or is the power always one less than the number to be powered?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely understand. Each value will be powered by a different number?

Comment: @StephenCowley There will always be 8 numbers (which will vary in value) in the list and the first exponent with the first number in the list will begin at 0. So the number in index 0, will have a power of 0. The second number at index 1 will have a power of 1 and so on..

Comment: @HelenaMartins Each value should be powered in consecutive order starting at 0. The first number in the list should be powered by 0, the second number should be powered by 1, the third number should be powered by 2... However if the the third item in the list is 'None' then you should still continue with the consecutive order for the next item in the list. Continuing the sequence the 4 item in the list should have a power of 3.

Comment: Got it! Below is my answer to your question :) In case of doubt, just give me a hint

Comment: @HelenaMartins Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could get you started?

```
import numpy as np

l = [1, None, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

# If you need to define the powers
# powers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

powers = np.arange(len(l)) # If powers are always indices

arr = np.array([x if x is not None else 0 for x in l])

arr**powers
# array([      1,       0,       9,      64,     625,    7776,  117649, 2097152]

(arr**powers).sum()
# 2223276
```

---

On second thought, the above would have a problem if you had `[None, 1, 2, 3]` since `0**0`=`1`. So we should probably go with something like

```
l = [1, None, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

numbers = np.array([x for x in l if x is not None])
powers = np.array([i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] is not None])
(numbers**powers).sum()
```

Comment: What if the first item at index 0 is a none value then it will return 1. Would the best way to fix this to be by checking index 0 for a 'None' Value then assigning a 0?

Comment: @Dom_Codes You're exactly right. The second part of my answer addresses that

Comment: I'd just suggest to replace the `powers = np.arange(8)` with `powers = np.arange(len(l))`. More versatile and less hard code ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
List = [1,None,3,4,5,6,7,8]
result = sum([pow(List[i],i) for i in range(len(List)) if str(List[i]).isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use list comprehension to only pow numeric values:

```
index_list = range(len(list))

sum([pow(list[i], i) for i in index_list if str(list[i]).isdigit()])
#Output: 2223276
```

In here, we sum a list that contains all values powered by an exponent. It will only sum numeric values!